# Shopify API error response "All line items of a fulfillment must use the same fulfillment service"

Tags: api, e-commerce, shopify

I am trying to add fulfillment for multiple(all) line items in an order. Following is the sample XML that I am generating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <fulfillment>
    <line-items type="array">
      <line-item>
        <id>1234567</id>
        <fulfillment-status>fulfilled</fulfillment-status>
        <fulfillment-service>USPS</fulfillment-service>
      </line-item>
      <line-item>
        <id>1234568</id>
        <fulfillment-status>fulfilled</fulfillment-status>
        <fulfillment-service>USPS</fulfillment-service>
      </line-item>
    </line-items>
    <notify-customer type="boolean">true</notify-customer>
    <tracking-number>4545454545454545</tracking-number>
  </fulfillment>
```

But I get the following response from Shopify:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
  <error>All line items of a fulfillment must use the same fulfillment service</error>
</errors>
```

Note that above are the only two line items in the Order and none of these line items have been fulfilled yet.

In which cases does Shopify respond back with the above error?
What am I doing incorrect thats causing the above error response & What can I do to add the fulfillments correctly?

Comment: I get the same error message even if I try to update fulfillment for all items of the Order by not specifying the line-items at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopify gives the above error if you have a Custom Order Fulfillment method defined in Shopify Admin under Settings --> Shipping
The error message "All line items of a fulfillment must use the same fulfillment service" does not seem appropriate as it shows even if we are passing the same same fulfillment service for all line items in the order.

Comment: Come across the same issue when two products in an order with same customized fulfillment service, one without variant, another with variant, is not allowed to be updated with fulfillment service. Have you fixed it dude?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is occurring is because the variants in the shop don't have the same fulfillment service specified. If the line items are being fulfilled via different services, it would follow that a single tracking number won't suffice.